# Update a Record containing Identity Element using Stored Proc in LinqtoSQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, identity-column

I have a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[procInfo](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [startTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [endTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [procName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_procInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I start a Process, I create a record for it using a LinQtoSQL Stored Procedure from my c# code.
Now when the process ends, I want to update the same record with the `endtime`. The `id` should remain same as it is referenced by other tables.
I am aware of the SQL queries:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[procInfo] ON
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[procInfo] OFF
```

I have a way to store the id if the process that has finished. Now, I want to write a stored Procedure to update this record with the `endTime`. I have been trying various things, but none of those are working.
Any suggestions on how to do this ?

Comment: I had framed `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[procInfo] ON` and the update query as two separate queries. So when I executed the update query, I found the flag `IDENTITY_INSERT` still `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but couldn't you simply use an UPDATE query?

```
UPDATE procInfo
SET endTime = <end time>
WHERE id = <process id>
```

It should be quite straightforward.

Comment: Yes I did that finally. I was breaking my head beating around the bush. Thank anyways.

Answer (score 0):

ahh, I found an easier way to do this.
I could just write a stored proc as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertProcEndTime
(
@id int,
@endtime datetime
)
AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */
UPDATE procInfo
SET endTime = @endtime
WHERE id = @id

RETURN
```

...and it worked. No need to modify `IDENTITY_INSERT` flag.
Keep It Simple Stupid !!

Comment: Actually, you never had the need of modifying the IDENTITY_INSERT in the first place, since yours was an UPDATE. That's why I was wondering if there was some odd constraint for not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Once a record is inserted you can get IDENTITY using the query [SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

With the help of this IDENTITY then you can update the endtime

> [SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) It returns the last IDENTITY value
>   produced on a connection and by a statement in the same scope,
>   regardless of the table that produced the value. SCOPE_IDENTITY(),
>   like @@IDENTITY, will return the last identity value created in the
>   current session, but it will also limit it to your current scope as
>   well. In other words, it will return the last identity value that you
>   explicitly created, rather than any identity that was created by a
>   trigger or a user defined function.